# Table values not displaying in vf page

Tags: apex, visualforce

Table values not displaying in visual force page

VF page  code:

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" standardController="Maxval__c"  extensions="pageredirect">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="Enter Information">
            <apex:pageBlockSection >
                <apex:inputField value="{!Maxval__c.Name}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Maxval__c.Field_A__c}"/> 
                <apex:inputField value="{!Maxval__c.Field_B__c}"/> 
                <apex:inputField value="{!Maxval__c.Field_C__c}"/> 
                <apex:inputField value="{!Maxval__c.Field_D__c}"/> 
                <apex:inputField value="{!Maxval__c.Field_E__c}"/> 
                <div align="center">
                    <apex:commandButton action="{!redirect}" value="save"/>
                </div>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlock title="Recent Records">
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Records Info" collapsible="false">
                <div align="center">
                    <apex:pageblockTable value="{!acc}" var="a">
                        <apex:column value="{!a.Name}"/>
                        <apex:column value="{!a.Field_A__c}"/>
                        <apex:column value="{!a.Field_B__c}"/>
                        <apex:column value="{!a.Field_C__c}"/>
                        <apex:column value="{!a.Field_D__c}"/>
                        <apex:column value="{!a.Field_E__c}"/>
                    </apex:pageblockTable> 
                </div>  
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Extension Controller:

```
public with sharing class pageredirect
{    
    Public List<Maxval__c> acc{get;set;}
    public List<Maxval__c> getacc()
    {        
        acc = [select id,Name,Field_A__c,Field_B__c,Field_C__c,Field_D__c,Field_E__c from Maxval__c ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10];
        return acc;       
    }

    Maxval__c request;
    private Apexpages.standardcontroller controller; 
    public pageredirect(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
    {
        this.controller = controller;
    }

    public pagereference redirect()
    {
        controller.save();
        pagereference ref = page.Maxval;
        ref.setRedirect(true);
        return ref;        
    }
}
```

[image: Current output]

Comment: This is probably because you have two getters and Salesforce doesn't know which one to call. Please replace this line: `Public List<Maxval__c> acc{get;set;}` by `Private List<Maxval__c> acc;`

Comment: if you want to see just recent records added in this form then you have to refresh the page

Answer (score 1):

Major issue is Naming convention for getting account from controller because as **@Martin Lezer** said you have two getters and Salesforce doesn't know which one to call.

You need to change the method name for `getacc()`

replace method name in class and visualforce page as well.

what i have changed name of method is : `getaccountlist()`

**Apex Class :**

```
public List<Maxval__c> getaccountlist()
{        
    acc = [select id,Name,Field_A__c,Field_B__c,Field_C__c,Field_D__c,Field_E__c from Maxval__c ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10];
    return acc;       
}
```

what i have changed name of value to get accounts from controller is : `accountlist`

**Visualforce page**

```
<apex:pageblockTable value="{!accountlist}" var="a">
    <apex:column value="{!a.Name}"/>
    <apex:column value="{!a.Field_A__c}"/>
    <apex:column value="{!a.Field_B__c}"/>
    <apex:column value="{!a.Field_C__c}"/>
    <apex:column value="{!a.Field_D__c}"/>
    <apex:column value="{!a.Field_E__c}"/>
</apex:pageblockTable>
```

Comment: Please explain what you corrected in his code and just post the part with the problem.

Comment: @MartinLezer , i have updated my answer please correct me if i am wrong somewhere :)